# git multiple subject prefix with format-patch

Tags: git, patch, format-patch

I wanted to add more then one subject prefix to my patch while using the `format-patch` option of git.

The subject should look something like

```
[Qemu-devel] [PATCH] linux-user/qemu.h Changed ..........
```

How to do this?

---

Doing

```
git format-patch --subject-prefix="Qemu-Devel PATCH" .....
```

Results in

```
[Qemu-Devel PATCH] linux-user/qemu.h Changed ..........
```

Comment: From the documentation:  By default, the subject of a single patch is "[PATCH] First Line" and the subject when multiple patches are output is "[PATCH n/m] First Line". To force 1/1 to be added for a single patch, use -n. To omit patch numbers from the subject, use -N.

Answer (score 2):

You could do this:

```
git format-patch --subject-prefix="Qemu-Devel] [PATCH"
```

The beginning and end square brackets will be added automatically resulting in

> Subject: [Qemu-Devel] [PATCH] ...

If you had more than 2 subject prefixes:

```
git format-patch --subject-prefix="Qemu-Devel] [Something-Else] [PATCH"
```

Comment: Thats a smart solution. :) Thanks

Answer (score 1):

You could setup a configuration file for the `format-patch`

> **CONFIGURATION**
>   You can specify extra mail header lines to be added to each message, defaults for the subject prefix and file suffix, number patches when outputting more than one patch, add "To" or "Cc:" headers, configure attachments, and sign off patches with configuration variables.

```
[format]
    headers = "Organization: git-foo\n"
    subjectprefix = CHANGE
    suffix = .txt
    numbered = auto
    to = <email>
    cc = <email>
    attach [ = mime-boundary-string ]
    signoff = true
```

Set the desired ***`subjectprefix`***

Comment: Yes, but that would suffer from the same problem as I explained in the question.

Comment: I miss the point: if you will configure your subject in the config it can be whatever you want. it can include `[]` chanraters

Comment: Ok. Yes then your answer can be used with Titus's answer. Yes, thanks.